# mongoimport error inserting documents: unknown operator: $id

Tags: mongodb, symfony, mongoimport, symfony-3.2

I need to fix an old system that has an API built in Symfony and has packages mananged with composer. Basically it has an export routine and an import routine that was working and doesn't work anymore.

The components of the system that could be related to the problem:

- "php": ">=7.1"
- "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*"
- "doctrine/orm": "^2.5"
- "doctrine/mongodb": "dev-master",
- "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
- "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0",
- MongoDB shell version: 3.2.22

I'm looking for help here because I would like to see if i can avoid starting heavy upgrades/downgrades to this system and I could not find anything useful in my searches.

Thanks in advance

There's a routine that creates a file *items_to_import.json* to be imported with items for each row formed like this one

```
{"_id":{"$id":"63ad55eb3c7d2216d8134158"},"current_fields":{"field1":"1234","field2":"blablabla"}}}
```

now importing a test file with a single line:

```
> mongoimport --db dbname --collection collectionname --upsert --file path/to/items_to_import.json
```

I get this import error:

```
> connected to: localhost
> error inserting documents: unknown operator: $id
> imported 1 document
```

and the item is not imported but skipped, the expected behavior is that the item is added/updated in the collection.

Comment: If you can somehow change `"$id"` to [`"$oid"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId), does it work for you then?

Comment: "_that was working and doesn't work anymore_" - what changed? Perhaps those details will help us isolate the problem and a minimal fix for it

Comment: further investigations the composer.json could have been changed slightly followed by composer update. So the difference from before and now could be a difference of the mongodb plugin for symfony that creates an export incompatibile with the mongodb from the system, that is unalterated from the update to the Symfony packages.

Comment: about changing manually $id in $oid makes it work with the file But the Symfony code exports with "$id" even if in the code have this line in it when setting the _id for the line to export.

```
$itemArray['_id'] = ['$oid' => (string)$itemArray['_id']];
```